# Cleaner way to check if variable exists and compare its value in PHP?

Tags: php

I was getting a lot of null index warnings so I need to check to make sure an object exists before trying to compare a property of that object to another value but I am left wondering if there is a more elegant way of writing the following:

```
if (isset($foo)) {
    if ($foo['bar'] == "Hello World") {
        //do something
    }
}
```

Edit: Needed to clarify that I was checking a property of the object (which is where a null object warning would be generated) not the object itself.

Answer (score 7):

No need for two `if` statements. Just use one:

```
if (isset($foo) && $foo == $bar) {
```

Comment: That makes sense in that case. I, however, phrased my original question in the wrong way. I need to check a property of the first object against another value but could be receiving a null object.